# How to add several products by checking user Id asp .net ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, linq-to-sql

I have a basket table in database and for every browser I create SessionId then when they add product to basket I take session Id and product Id. for example if customer adds 3 different product that means 3 rows in a database like;

```
SessionId ProductId ProductName ProductPrice Quantity   
User1     1         Product1    100$         1
User1     2         Product2    1$           2
User1     3         Product3    2$           3
```

SessionId is not primary there is ID column which is primary

So I list these with repeater in checkOut page here the repeater ;

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="reporder">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <tr class="checkout_table_item">
    <td class="product-name"><%#Eval("ProductName") %> 
    <strong class="product-quantity">× <%#Eval("ProductQuantity") %></strong></td>
    <td class="product-total"><span class="amount"><%#Eval("ProductPrice") %>
    </span></td></tr>
 </ItemTemplate></asp:Repeater>
```

And here the code for listing and getting total price ;

```
var q = (from d in db.Basket
         where d.UserId == Session.SessionID
         select d).ToList();

reporder.DataSource = q;
reporder.DataBind();

var TotalPrice = q.Aggregate(0D, (runningTotal, next) =>
runningTotal + (Convert.ToDouble(next.ProductQuantity) * 
Convert.ToDouble(next.ProductPrice)));

total.Text = TotalPrice.ToString();
```

And when I click Buy button I run ajax to get these items to orderproduct table here the code for webservice that I use ;

```
 int countUser= db.Basket.Count(x => x.UserId == Ip);
            for(int i= 0; i <= countUser; i++)
            {


                Basket basketProduct = db.Basket.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserId == Ip);
                OrderProduct create1 = new OrderProduct();
                create1.ProductId = basketProduct.ProductId;
                create1.ProductName = basketProduct.ProductName;
                create1.ProductPrice = basketProduct.ProductPrice;
                create1.ProductQuantity = basketProduct.ProductQuantity;
                create1.UserId = Ip;


                db.OrderProduct.Add(create1);
                db.SaveChanges();


            }
```

But when I run this the problem is I can't get different products. as I said if user1 adds 3 items I only get product1 3 times.How can I save to orderProduct table just like my basket table as above.

it becomes ;

```
SessionId ProductId ProductName ProductPrice Quantity   
User1     1         Product1    100$         1
User1     1         Product1    100$         1
User1     1         Product1    100$         1
```

I must do something like ; if user 1 has product1 in the order table get other product for user1. So thats why I tried to count user to add but it didnt work it counts it adds as much as product but it adds same product over and over again

Comment: The first thing I would do is make sure that `q` holds the right values. If not, then there is something wrong with the query to fetch the data.

Comment: q holds the right values there is no problem everything works perfectly only problems that I cant add products of user to order table. As you see I already dont use repeater or q to save. I use them to list then in my webservice I control table then I save from basket table to order table

Comment: actually I only use ajax to deliver sessionId so I get the session Id for basket table I control basket table if there are any products with that sessionId then I try to save to my order table but it saves 1 product for several times

Comment: I think I see.  In your web service you always call `firstordefault()` - which always returns the first result! It never increments.  You need to iterate thru the basketProducts and not just use the first one.

Comment: yes u are right but what should I do ? do u have any code example to help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work.  (Hope it compiles, I'm just free-typing.)  I think you get the idea, though.

```
            int countUser = db.Basket.Count(x => x.UserId == Ip);
        var basketProductList = db.Basket.Where(x => x.UserId == Ip).ToList();

        foreach (var basket in basketProductList)
        {
            OrderProduct create1 = new OrderProduct();
            create1.ProductId = basket.ProductId;
            create1.ProductName = basket.ProductName;
            create1.ProductPrice = basket.ProductPrice;
            create1.ProductQuantity = basket.ProductQuantity;
            create1.UserId = Ip;

            db.OrderProduct.Add(create1);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you also help me for if these products is added to orderproduct table then it should be deleted from basket table

Comment: Sure - What version of EF are you using?

Comment: You should use the same looping as in my answer.  Then call `DeleteObject()` on the objects. At the end, `SaveChanges()` will commit.  HTH!  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.deleteobject.aspx

Comment: Thx m8 I'm gonna check this out